# use parameterized constructor in other classes constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, instance-variables, default-constructor

I fear that this is a very basic question, however, I was not able to solve it yet.

I have a `class A`

```
// classA.h
...

class ClassA {
    public:
        ClassA();
        ClassA(int foo);
    private:
        int _foo;

    ...

}

// classA.cpp

ClassA::ClassA() {
    _foo = 0;
}

ClassA::ClassA(int foo) {
    _foo = foo;
}

...
```

A second `class B` uses an instance of `class A` in the constructor:

```
// classB.h
...

#include "classA.h"

#define bar 5

class ClassB {
    public:
        ClassB();
    private:
        ClassA _objectA;

    ...

}

// classB.cpp

ClassB::ClassB() {
    _objectA = ClassA(bar);
}

...
```

Note that the default constructor of `class A` is never used. In fact in my real world use case it would not even make sense to use any kind of a default constructor as `_foo` has to be dynamically assigned.

However, if I remove the default constructor, the compiler returns an error:

> no matching function for call to 'ClassA::ClassA()'

Is there a way to use an instance of `class A` as an object in `class B` without defining a default constructor for `class A`? How would this be done?

Comment: *Note that the default constructor of class A is never used* -- With your current code, it is being used here: `ClassA _objectA;` even if you didn't mean to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor of `ClassA` is used. `ClassB`'s `_objectA` is initialized with it and *then* you assign `ClassA(bar)` to it.

You can solve your problem by using [constructor initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
ClassB::ClassB() : _objectA(bar)
{}
```

Comment: thank you! Your answer leads to a follow-up question, but it is a step further :)

Answer (score 3):

Just write

```
ClassB::ClassB() :  _objectA(bar)
{
}
```

The problem is that when the body of the constructor of the `ClassB` is executed the data member `_objectA` is already constructed and inside the body there is used the copy assignment operator

```
ClassB::ClassB() {
    _objectA = ClassA(bar);
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Thus you can remove the default constructor of the `ClassA`.

Comment: thank you! Your answer leads to a follow-up question, but it is a step further :)