# Constructor Initializer List - will this work?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

With your help I could solve the problem I described in this minimal example ([use parameterized constructor in other classes constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665414/use-parameterized-constructor-in-other-classes-constructor/40665458#40665458)) using a constructor initializer list.

In my real life problem, things are a bit more difficult. My constructor now looks somehow like this:

```
ClassC::ClassC() : _objectB(_objectA.getInt()) {
  _objectA = ClassA();
}
```

Will this work? The compiler doesn't return any errors. However, `_objectB` is initialized with a value of `_objectA`, which is initialized in the line below. So how would `_objectA.getInt()` return a valid value?

If it doesn't work, how can I make it work?

Comment: I'd use `ClassC::ClassC() : _objectA(), _objectB(_objectA.getInt()) {}`

Comment: What is your `ClassC` definition: I don't see where `_objectA` is defined. Not the one of  `_objectB` since scopes are different. If it is also a field of `class C` then you have 2 `_objectA` in your class which can be later confusing.

Comment: I have a header file with `ClassA _objectA;` and `ClassB _objectB;` in it. Sorry I did not mention that in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `_objectA` is declared like

```
class ClassC
{
    ClassA _objectA;
    ClassB _objectB;

    public:
    ClassC();
}
```

it will work, because `_objectA` is already initialized (with the default constructor), and you just reassign it a new class later, which has nothing to do with `_objectB` initialization.

---

However, as @πάντα ῥεῖ suggested it is better to use

```
ClassC::ClassC() : _objectA(), _objectB(_objectA.getInt()) {}
```

that will initialize `_objectA`, then use it for `_objectB` initialization.

Answer (score 2):

If _objectA is declared before _objectB, then _objectA's default constructor will be called.  And, _objectB will be initialzed with the getInt() value from _objectA.  Afterward, in the body of the constructor, _objectA is set via assignment operator with the default constructor of ClassA--which is unneeded.

If _objectB is declared before _objectA, then IDK...it may be compiler implementation dependent.

Either way, you are basically initializing _objectA twice.

Comment: thank you for your answer! It helped me a lot understanding c++ better!

Answer (score 2):

> So how would _objectA.getInt() return a valid value?

Most probably yes. If `objectA` is initialized using the default constructor to yield valid values, it is already constructed implicitly (if the declaration appears before `objectB`).

The assignment in the constructor body is superfluous.

Also it's better to write:

```
 ClassC::ClassC() : _objectA(), _objectB(_objectA.getInt()) {}
```

to make that clear in the member initializer list.

Answer (score 2):

Class members are always initialized in the order they're declared, so assuming `ClassC` looks something like

```
class ClassC
{
    ClassA _objectA;
    ClassB _objectB;

public:
    ClassC();
//...
};
```

then your constructor is equivalent to

```
ClassC::ClassC() : _objectA(), _objectB(_objectA.getInt()) {
    _objectA = ClassA();
}
```

As you can see, `_objectA` is initialized before `_objectB` and then later you copy-assign to `_objectA` from an anonymous `ClassA` object in the constructor's body.

Comment: thanks for your answer. very comprehensive and very helpful!